# Automatic event firing in a textbox while text is being typed

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, spell-checking

I m designing a spell checker for Indian language in asp.net using c#.

I have prepared all the modules. But, there is a problem using `TextBox` as I want it to tell the error while user types in the text and highlight that string.

I have done this on a button click but I am not able to do it directly without any button.   Is it possible using jquery or ajax tools to use a `TextBox` for firing an event while text is being typed? (I tried `TextChanged` event but it gets fired only when a `Button` is clicked in asp.net)

Comment: _"textchanged event gets fired only when a button is clicked"_ - without autopostback this is true, but perhaps an ASP.NET WebForms control isn't the right solution to this. Have you considered third-party controls?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `TextChanged` event handler.

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           TextBox tmp = sender as TextBox ;
           if(SpellCheck(tmp.Text))
           {
                    // No Error.
           }
           else
           {
                 // Error 
           }
    }
   // SpellCheck is a function checking the spelling(which you have to make.)
```

Make sure that

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

is there in your code.

Comment: but will this code be highlighting the words which are wrong as in word processors?

Comment: That function you will have to make yourself.  You said in your question that "I have done this on a button click but I am not able to do it directly without any button. ", With the above code, you can do it without the help of button

Comment: i was using a freetextbox to change the color of text that is wrongly spelled but is it possible to do it in the textbox provided in the asp.net?

Comment: please than suggest how to do it? i m stuck there

Answer (score 0):

you can use [onkeyup](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) of javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event and make to ajax call inside that event.

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
 //make ajax call to u'r function
});
```