# highlight certain text in a textbox in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, freetextbox

I need `TextBox` in **asp.net** to highlight some text when certain event occurs while text is being typed (as in **Microsoft Word** spell check feature).

I have been using freetextbox, it highlights the text on a button click but not automatically.

How to do that?
Should I use another control?

Comment: Could you give an example for a "certain event"?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257663/automatic-event-firing-in-a-textbox-while-text-is-being-typed

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again and again. You had already asked this question 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RichTextBox` for doing it.
With `RichTextBox`, you can color or highligh single lines or words.

```
    // select characters from index 0 to 9
     richTextBox1.Select(0, 10);

   //will color the selected text.
   richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
```

Check this [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/richtextbox) for a tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery and check for each keypress, when your word combination is met you can use css to highlight text.

function is .keypress() -  [more on keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)